# Show that if $f(x)=\int_{0}^x f(t)dt$, then $f=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I am having a problem with a question. Can somebody help me please.

Show that if $f(x)=\int_{0}^x f(t)dt$, then $f=0$

Thank you in advance

Comment: More precise assumptions on the function $f$ are needed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

differentiating both sides gives $f'(x) = f(x)$ which has solutions $f(x) = Ae^x$. But the original statement gives that $f(0) = \int_0^0f(t)dt = 0$ so we have $Ae^0 = 0$ so $A = 0$ and the function is constantly zero.

Comment: And we *can* "differentiate both sides"  because...?

Comment: You are assuming tacitly that $f$ is continuous, so that $x \mapsto \int_0^x f$ is differentiable, and hence $f$ is differentiable.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is continuous, the the argument suggested by Tom Oldfield gives the answer. If $f$ i only locally integrable, you can apply [Gronwall's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gronwall%27s_inequality#Integral_form_with_locally_finite_measures).
Choosing $\alpha =0$, you get $f \leq 0$. Applying the same reasoning to $-f$ you get $f \geq 0$. Hence $f=0$ identically.

PS: I think that a more direct proof can be found.

Comment: Since $f$ is integrable therefore $f$ is continuous and therefore $f$ is differentiable. No assumptions are needed.