# If $f\left(x\right)=\int\limits _{0}^{x}f\left(t\right)dt$ then $f \equiv 0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is a function that for all $0\leq a<b\in \mathbb R$, $f_{|[a,b]}:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is integrable.
assuming that for all $x\in[0,\infty)$ , $f\left(x\right)=\int\limits _{0}^{x}f\left(t\right)dt$ then $f\equiv0$

my attempt:

First we know that $f\left(x\right)=\int\limits _{0}^{x}f\left(t\right)dt$ so $f(x)$ is an anti derivative of itself and continuous on $[0,\infty)$ 
$$
f\left(x\right) = \int\limits _{0}^{x}f\left(t\right)dt\Rightarrow f\left(x\right)-f\left(0\right)=f\left(x\right)
 \Rightarrow f\left(0\right)=0
$$
Now according to Mean value theorem because $f$ is continuous and derivative on $[0,\infty)$ there exists $c\in[0,\infty)$ and
$$
f(c)=\frac{f\left(x\right)-f\left(0\right)}{x}\Rightarrow f\left(c\right)=\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x}
$$

It could be that this attempt will not lead me to a solution but this is all I got right now. if you have any ideas...

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/226093).

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1839457/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1626852/321264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a simpler method for that... As far as I know, there is only  function satisfying $F(x)=f(x)$ (where F is an antiderivative of f). This function is $f(x)=ae^x$ by definition of the exponential function. Giving your situation, $F(x) = 0$ for $x=0$ but $\forall x\in\Bbb R, e^x > 0$ so $a=0$. Then the only possible function $f$ satisfying $F(x)=f(x)$ is $f(x)=0$.

EDIT : you can also think using the air representation of the integral. $\int\limits_a^b f(x)dx$ is, when $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a;b]$, the algebric measure of the air bounded by $x=a, x=b, y=0$ and $y=f(x)$. So when you write $\int\limits_0^x f(t)dt=0$, this means that the air is null for all $x \in\Bbb R$. Then the only function having a null air over the reals is $f(x)=0$.

Comment: Actually, $f(x) = Ae^x$ will work for any constant $A$. $f(x) = 0$ is then just the special case $A = 0$.

Comment: Thanks, corrected the answer with your remark.

Comment: can we prove somehow that if $F(x)=f(x)$ then it has to be that $F(x)=ae^x$?

Comment: Here, there are no room for any proof, it's the definition of the exponential function. $exp(x)$ is defined as the unique non-zero function having the property $exp(x)'=exp(x)$.

Comment: Your question is like trying to prove that $i^2=-1$. You can't prove it's a definition. It is so because mathematicians created these so.

Comment: @bob If $f'=f$, compute $(f/e^x)'$. You'll see it's zero; so $f=Ce^x$ for some constant $C$. moray: one can define the exponential function as *a* non-zero function that is its own derivative. Showing that such a function exists and that it is unique does require proof.

Comment: @DavidMitra Yes, you need proof to show that it's unique and it exist but you don't need proof for showing that $exp'(x)=exp(x)$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you that is what i was missing. moray95 you are right about $exp'(x)=exp(x)$ but i wasn't sure about the other direction.

Comment: @moray95 $\exp$ may be defined differently. For example, as the inverse of $\log$, which is defined via integrals, $\displaystyle\ln(t)=\int_1^t\frac{du}u$. Or via the power series expansion, $\displaystyle \exp(x)=\sum_n\frac{x^n}{n!}$. Or as the unique continuous $f$ with $f(1)=e$, $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$. Different authors follow different approaches. In any case, under any of these alternative (but standard) approaches, that $\exp(x)'=\exp(x)$ needs to be proved. Anyway, you need to be careful, as the differential equation does not define $\exp$. You also need the initial condition $\exp(0)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x)=\mathrm e^{-x}f(x)$. Then
$$g'(x)=f'(x)\mathrm e^{-x}-f(x)\mathrm e^{-x}=0.$$
As $g(0)=0$, we have $g(x)=0$, for all $x$, and the result follows.

Comment: It is related to a recent similar [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648706/should-fx-equiv-0)