# Let $f$ be a differentiable function such that $f(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f$ be a differentiable on $(0,\infty)$function such that $f(0)=0$

$0 \le f'(x) \le x.f(x) \forall x \in (0,\infty)$ then show that $f(x)=0$

My attempt:

Solving the equation I got

$A_1 \le f(x) \le Ae^{x^2}$

Now $f(0)=0$ then $A_1\le0$ and $A \ge 0$.

I don't think we can claim that $f(x)=0$.

Is the question wrong? Or else where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Am I missing something?

$f(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}$ vanishes at $x=0$ and $f'(x)\le x$ $\forall x\in (0,\infty)$.

Comment: I think it's supposed to read $f'(x) \leqslant xf(x)$, I'm not sure..

Comment: I would like to see how you "Solving the equation I got

"

Comment: This is Gronwall's inequality. Just repeat the steps of the proof.

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/648706/9911 (there the inequality is $f'(x) \le f(x)$)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming continuity on $[0,\infty)$ we get $(e^{-x^{2}/2}f(x))'\leq 0$ so $e^{-x^{2}/2}f(x)$ is decreasing on $[0,\infty)$ and $0\leq e^{-x^{2}/2}f(x) \leq e^{0}f(0)=0$. [$f(x) \geq 0$ because $f$ is increasing and $f(0)=0$].

Without continuity at $0$ the assumption that $f(0)=0$ is of no use and the result is false.

Comment: $e^{-x^2/2}f(x)$ is a decreasing function and it is less than $0$. How would that ensure $f(x)=0$?

Comment: Is it because of the fact that $f'(x) \ge 0$ and $f(x)$ is an increasing function?

Comment: What if it is of the form $0 \le f'(x) \le sinxf(x)$ ?

Comment: @Antimony I have added some details.

Comment: @Antimony $\sin x \leq x$ for all $x \geq 0$ so $0\leq f'(x)\leq \sin x f(x)$ also has the same answer.