# Prove that if $f(x) = \int_{0}^x f(t)\,dt$, then $f(x) = 0$

Tags: calculus

> Prove that if $f(x) = \displaystyle\int_{0}^x f(t)\, dt$ for all $x$, then $f(x) = 0$.

I first differentiated to get $f'(x) = f(x) - f(0)$. Then by the mean value theorem there exists a $c$ in $(0,x)$ such that $f'(c)=\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$. Thus, $f'(x) = xf'(c)$. What do I do from here?

A summary of the deliberation in the comments about the necessity of assumptions on $f$:

There was worry that we needed assumptions on $f$ such as continuity in order to exploit FTC.

> Thanks to Aloizio and Clark for pointing out that no assumptions need be placed on $f$ as the integral of a Riemann integrable function is continuous. This gives us that $f$ is continuous (since by assumption we have that $f$ is integrable) and thus the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus applies.

Comment: How do we know that $f$ is differentiable?

Comment: We should assume that $f$ is continuous for this problem. That would be sufficient.

Comment: @stefan $\int _{0}^xf(t) dt $ is continuous therefore $f(x) $ is continuous therefore $f$ is diff

Comment: This was a problem from my book and it didn't say it was differentiable.

Comment: @Stefan4024 If $f$ is simply integrable, its integral is continuous, which means $f$ is continuous, so when you integrate it you get a differentiable function. In a lot of situations like this, you get smoothness for free.

Comment: see that $f(0)=0$ then (if $f$ is integrable tinks to @CameronWilliams) f is a solution of $y'=y$ with $y(0)=0$ then $y=0$

Comment: @CameronWilliams I noticed that. It follows from the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. I rushed to make a conclusion.

Comment: @Puzzled417 You made a little bit of a mistake. When you differentiate, you get $f'(x) = f(x)$. The lower limit is ineffectual since it is a constant independent of $x$. What then do you know about $f$? If you plug in $x=0$ into your integral equation, what does that tell you?

Comment: @clark How does "$f(x)\;$ is continuous" follow from "$\int_0^x f(t)dt\;$ is continuous"? I understand that "$\;f(x)\;$ is continuous $\;\implies \int_0^x f(t)dt=f(x)\;$ is differentiable" by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, though.

Comment: @Joanpemo $f(x) = \int _{0}^ {x}f(t)d t$ so if the RHS is continuous so is the LHS. The RHS is absolutely continuous as long as $f$ is an integrable function

Comment: @clark Thank you, exactly my point. It looked in your comment like you deduce continuity of the function from continuity of the integral, which in general isn't true. Of course, in **this** case it follows as the function equals that integral.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/226093/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1626852/321264.

Answer (score 10):

Firstly, we know $f$ is continuous, since $\int_0^x f$ is a continuous function when $f$ is Riemann-integrable, or even Lebesgue-integrable (which I'm assuming is the case since otherwise this doesn't make sense). Now, we then have by the FTC that $f$ is differentiable, and it follows that $f'(x)=f(x)$ for all $x$ also due to the FTC. Since $f(0)=0$, we are done.

---

"Order of information": We look at the right side, and see that it is a continuous function on $x$ due to the fact that $f$ is integrable. Therefore, the left side is continuous. Looking at the right side now, we have the integration up to $x$ of a continuous function, which is differentiable by the FTC.

Comment: @Puzzled417 Because $f(x)=\int_0^x g$. It doesn't even matter that it is the integral of itself up to $x$, it only matter that it is the integral of *something* up to $x$. This makes $f$ a continuous function, regardless of $g$ being continuous or not.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $f$ is continuous. The fundamental theorem of calculus tells us that it is actually differentiable, and moreover by differentiating both sides we get

$$f'(x) = f(x)$$

So $f(x)$ is a function which is its own derivative, and hence is of the form $f(x) = ce^{x}$. What is the constant $c$? Simply compute

$$f(0) = \int_{0}^{0} f(x) = 0$$

to see that $c = 0$, and we are done.

Comment: How do you know that the only continuous functions equal to their own derivative at every point $x$ are of the form $f(x) = ce^x$?

Comment: You dont need to "suppose $f$ is continuous".

Answer (score 2):

As noted elsewhere, if $f(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$ for $x\ge 0$, then $f$ is necessarily continuous. 
Being continuous, there is a point $x_0\in[0,1/2]$ such that $f(x_0)\ge f(x)$ for all $x\in[0,1/2]$.  Notice that $f(x_0)\ge f(0)=0$. We then have
$$
f(x_0)=\int_0^{x_0}f(t)\,dt\le\int_0^{x_0}f(x_0)\,dt=x_0f(x_0).
$$
Thus, either $f(x_0)=0$ or   $1\le x_0$, which is absurd. We conclude that $f(x_0)=0$, and so $f(x)\le 0$ for all $x\in[0,1/2]$. In the same way $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\in[0,1/2]$. That is, $f$ vanishes on $[0,1/2]$. Repeat this argument on $[1/2,1], [1,3/2],\ldots$ to conclude that $f$ is identically $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that differentiating $f$ is legal, and using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (FTC),

$$f' (x) = f(x)$$

Integrating,

$$f (x) = f_0 \exp (x)$$

We note that $f (0) = 0$. Hence, $f_0 = 0$ and, thus, $f (x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $f'=f.$

(1). We have $f(0)=\int_0^0f(x)\;dx=0.$

(2). For any $x,$if $f(x)=0$ then $f(y)=0$ for all $y\in [-1+x,1+x]. $ PROOF: For convenience, for $a\ne b$ let $In (a,b)$ denote the open interval between $a$ and $b$.

Now for $0<|y-x|< 1$ we have $$f(y)/(y-x)=(f(y)-f(x))/(y-x)=f'(y')=f(y')$$ for some  $y' \in In (y,x),$  by the MVT and by $f'=f$. So there exists $y'\in In (y,x)$ satisfying $$f(y)=(y-x)f(y').$$

So there exists $(y_n)_{n\geq 0}$ with $y_0=y$, and  $y_{n+1}\in In (y_n,x), $ where $y_{n+1}$ satisfies  $f(y_n)=(y_n-x)f(y_{n+1}).$ Let $M=\max \{|f(z)|: 0\leq |z-x|\leq 1\}.$  Then $$|f(y)|=|f(y_{n+1})\prod_{i=1}^n(y_n-y)|\leq M |y-x|^n,$$ which $\to 0$ as $n\to \infty.$  Therefore $|y-x|<1\implies f(y)=0.$ Then by continuity of $f$ we also have $f(x-1)=f(x+1)=0.$

(3).By (1) and(2) we have $f^{-1}\{0\}\supset [-1,1].$

Now for $n\in N,$ if $f^{-1}\{0\}\supset [-n,n]$ then  by (2) we have $f^{-1}\{0\}\supset [n-1,n+1]$ and $f^{-1}\{0\}\supset [-n-1,-n+1],$ giving $$f^{-1}\{0\}\supset [-n-1,-n+1]\cup [-n,n]\cup [n,n+1]=[-n-1,n+1].$$ Hence by induction on $n$ we have $$f^{-1}\{0\}=\mathbb R.$$