# If $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}{f(t)}dt$ then $f(x)=0$

Tags: integration

$f(x)$ is integrable in every interval in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\forall \ x \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}{f(t)}dt$

I need to prove that $f(x)=0 \ \forall \ x$

Can someone give a clue? Thanks!

Comment: Welcime to MSE, please use  [Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference) to type your question. And also please add at least what have you tried so that others can help you.

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/226093).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

What's the derivative of $f$?

Comment: I think it is f(x)?

Comment: @david Correct. Now, do you know anything about differential equations?

Comment: yes, but can you explain me? thanks

Comment: @david Well, what's the family of functions that satisfies the property "the derivative of the function is the function itself"?

Comment: it can be only f(x)=0?

Comment: @david Are you **sure** you know about differential equations? What about $e^x$? and $2e^x$?

Comment: ya sorry, e^x'=e^x and c*e^x'=c*e^x for every c in R

Comment: @david Correct. Now, you know that $f(x)=C\cdot e^x$ for some $C\in\mathbb R$. You need to determine $C$. To do that, look at the value of $f(0)$.

Comment: understood!! thanks!!!

Comment: @david If this answer is what you needed, you can also upvote and accept it. This is how the site works.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to notice this: the function $f$ is only assumed to be integrable, so a priori you can't say anything about the derivative of $\int_{0}^x f(t)dt$, unless you notice that the fundamental theorem of calculus says you that $f(x) = \int_{0}^x f(t)dt$ is continous at every point, now you can apply further the fundamental theorem of calculus to calculate that $f' = f$ and the claim easily follows as discussed in comments